# Go: split a string of key/value pairs separated by commas, with potential embedded commas within a given key/value pair

Tags: regex, go

I'm fairly new to the Go language and am looking for a way to split a variable length string into a map with key/value pairs (all strings) separated by commas, only some variations of the string may have multiple commas and/or colons within a given key/value pair. For example:

**String1 variation**
keyword1=value1,keyword2=value2,keyword3=value3,value4,value5,keyword4=value6 ...
**String2 variation**
keyword1=value1,keyword2=value2,keyword3=value3,value4,value5:value6,value7,value8,keyword4=value9 ...

where "..." reflects the fact that there will be a variable # of key/value pairs. I would like to end up with a map like:

```
map[string]string{
     
            keyword1: "value1",
            keyword2: "value2",
            keyword3: "value3,value4,value5",
            keyword4: "valu6",
    }
```

or

```
map[string]string{
     
            keyword1: "value1",
            keyword2: "value2",
            keyword3: "value3,value4,value5:value6,value7,value8",
            keyword4: "valu6",
    }
```

Unfortunately the format of lines I will be reading from the file is fairly convoluted and I have limited options for changing the incoming data format. I have been spinning my wheels at this for a while and unfortunately I'm no wizard with regex's, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to Go's draconian regex implementation, which doesn't support look aheads, the easiest solution is to find a library that does support it and split on `,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$")'`

Comment: @Bohemian if you give up on the idea of splitting, you don't need lookaheads (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match (globally), not split, then you don't need lookaround: [`(.*?)=([^=]*)(?:,|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/0IYcKv/2). In Go:

```golang
package kvparse

import (
    "regexp"
    "testing"
    "reflect"
)

var kvPairRe = regexp.MustCompile(`(.*?)=([^=]*)(?:,|$)`)
func ParseKV(kvStr string) map[string]string {
    res := map[string]string{}
    for _, kv := range kvPairRe.FindAllStringSubmatch(kvStr, -1) {
        res[kv[1]] = kv[2]
    }
    return res
}

func TestParseKV(t *testing.T) {
    test := func(kvStr string, expectedMap map[string]string) {
        gotMap := ParseKV(kvStr)
        if !reflect.DeepEqual(expectedMap, gotMap) {
            t.Errorf("Abs(%s) = %v; want %v", kvStr, gotMap, expectedMap)
        }
    }
    test("keyword1=value1,keyword2=value2,keyword3=value3,value4,value5,keyword4=value6",
        map[string]string{ "keyword1": "value1", "keyword2": "value2", "keyword3": "value3,value4,value5", "keyword4": "value6" })
    test("keyword1=value1,keyword2=value2,keyword3=value3,value4,value5:value6,value7,value8,keyword4=value9",
        map[string]string{ "keyword1": "value1", "keyword2": "value2", "keyword3": "value3,value4,value5:value6,value7,value8", "keyword4": "value9" })
}
```

Comment: Luatic's answer worked like a charm! Thanks for the incredibly quick turnaround. This even handles some characters within the value pairs like "(", ")" and  "-", that I had forgotten to mention. You made my day :)

Comment: @RWiggumUK you're welcome :) I'm always happy to come up with a true regex solution - not a fan of all those non-polynomial-time backtracking engines and all their crazy features ;)